# MVC Entity Framework , The Entity Types cannot share table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Error: https://imgur.com/a/TbG6M

I have 2 tables which are unrelated to each other. Employee, and Patient.

Note (both database calls for both entities are being called in the same Controller, EmployeeController. Please check the gist I linked below)

I'm trying to get a List of Patients after a successful Login attempt from an Employee. Here is how the flow of work should go:

- Employee enters Username and Password, then presses a Login button which invokes Login(Employee MyEmployee). (This is inside the EmployeeController)
- After a successful login, Login() function RedirectToAction("Main");which calls my context class to get the Patients.
- Error is in imgur link above.
- I'll add a gist for you guys to see all the related file.

gist: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/95ffda179eb690e8a9efbdc5cb1aa15c

[HttpPost]

```
    public ActionResult Login(Employee MyEmployee)
    {
        EmployeeBusinessLayer MyEmployeeBusinessLayer = new EmployeeBusinessLayer();

        List<Employee> MyEmployeeLst = MyEmployeeBusinessLayer.GetEmployeesByID(MyEmployee.UserName, MyEmployee.Password);

        if (MyEmployeeLst.Count > 0)

        {

            Session["EmployeeID"] = MyEmployeeLst[0].ID;

            Session["UserName"] = MyEmployeeLst[0].UserName;

            return RedirectToAction("Main");

        }

        else

        {

            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Username or password is wrong");

        }

        return View();

    }
```

The Main() function:

```
public ActionResult Main()
        {
            if (Session["EmployeeID"] != null)
            {
                PatientBusinessLayer PBL = new PatientBusinessLayer();
               List<Patient> MyPatientLst = PBL.GetPatients();
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Well, in your `Patient` related db context you have `modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().ToTable("Patient");`. It should be `modelBuilder.Entity<Patient>()...`

Comment: Hi Ivan. Thank you, I changed that to Patient, but for some reason it's returning an empty list now (there is 1 record in Patient)